# Multi-language/country web projects

Tags: web, multilingual

I plan to build a websites that come to target specific countries and each country should be translated to theirs language/s (ie. Canada speak both English and French).

I've many questions but I think I first need to visit websites that target multiple countries and languages to get some inspiration and see how they did.

So to this post I hope you can give me example of websites that target multiple countries which also mean languages.

/Mike

Update: I can add that I looking after user content (community) websites.

Comment: What programming language? The approaches are different.

Comment: You really just want a list of websites that have different language versions?

Comment: Brabster - Yes, but not only language - primary countries.

Comment: Silky: In this case, I want to be general because I don't think the approach is different if I use ASP.NET, Rails or PHP.

Comment: @mike it's too general IMO. Different languages have different tools for this, even if the approaches are identical.

Comment: Does "multi-lang" mean?  It's not a word.  Do you mean "multi-lingual" or "multi-language" or "internationalized"?  Please replace "multi-lang" with a real word or phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/) does target different countries and languages in a nice way.

Answer (score 1):

Most big corporates will do the multi-country, multi-language thing.

eg.

- [HSBC](http://www.hsbc.com)
- [IBM](http://www.ibm.com)
- [Boeing](http://boeing.com/worldwide.html)
- [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/uk/function/ipredirection/ipredirectionLocalList.do)